# HelloAnalytics guzzle error in local

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics, google-api-php-client, guzzle

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60:
>   SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\analytics\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:187
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\analytics\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(150):
>   GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle),
>   Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\analytics\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(103):
>   GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\analytics\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43):
>   GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\analytics\vendor\gu in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\analytics\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php
>   on line 187

Here the steps i have done:

1.installed the composer.exe from this [Download Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

2.then i have opened the command promt in that when i type composer i can see that the composer has installed on my pc.

3.i have added a service account and downloaded my json file and incuded in the same project folder.

4.added tracking script to my website footer.

5.when i run composer.json the google client library is downloaded.

6.Added a HelloAnalytics.php to see the results.

when i start my xampp and run the HelloAnlytics page this guzzle error is coming how can i resolve this.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - SSL certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.I have downloaded cacert.pem file from this url [cacert file download](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) .

2. Save cacert.pem file in **xampp/php/ext/cacert.pem**
3. UN-comment and give the path to it in php.ini file:
   near line 1980 try finding `ctrl` + `F` curl

**`;curl.cainfo =`**

replace this line with this..

```
curl.cainfo =C:\xampp\php\ext\cacert.pem
```

for details information of installation you can check it out here [Description of how to integrate google analytic's](http://techdefeat.com/download-and-install-composer-in-windows-10)